# Fastest dictionary based edit distance

Tags: performance, solr, edit-distance

I have a dictionary of strings (7 million strings). I have a list queries/strings (30 million strings) i want to run against the dictionary.

I want to get all the dictionary matches having edit distance 1 or 2 for a given query.

At present i am using solr to do this. I have indexed 7 million strings in solr (2GB index size). I am using strdist() function to get the matches. But this approach is taking 300 to 500 ms on average for each query. It will take 104 days to complete 30 million queries.

I tried solr MMapDirectory approach also but i did not find any performance difference. I tried increasing documentCache, queryResultCache also but it did not improve performance much.

Can i improve this performance to 1 ms using solr or any other approach other than solr ? Is there any better option than solr here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [fuzzy search support](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) instead. It uses edit distance as its underlying comparison, and supports edit distances up to 2 (which should be enough for your need).

Another possibility is to create a simpler query that you filter against first, but exactly what that query would look like depends on your input and matching data (for some use cases a phonetic search works fine as the first step).

Comment: My dictionary and query contains strings of multiple words. Fuzzy search does not work in that case. For example, i have _Google Corporation_ in my index and my query is _Google Corportion_. When i run this query i expect it to match with this entry in dictionary as it is of edit distance 1. Fuzzy search cannot be applied in this case.

Comment: Why can't fuzzy search be applied in that case?

Comment: I want edit distance match for complete string and not for individual words in a string. Different ways i can apply edit distance here are                                            1. _Google Corportion~1_ : matches entries like _sony corporation_, _microsoft corporation_ etc                                                                           2. _Google~1 Corportion~1_ : It also matches entries like _sony corporation_, microsoft corporation_ etc                                                           3. "_Google Corportion_"~1 :  this will do proximity search

Comment: That depends on your field type - use a StrField or a TextField with just a KeywordTokenizer and a LowercaseFilter if you need to match it without considering case. It should be related to your tokens - not the usage of fuzzy search.

Comment: It is not the issue with tokens, it is the issue with fuzzy search. I am using simply StrField. As per [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) , you can use fuzzy search only on single word term